# SQL QUERY - AGGREGATION AND FORMAT

Tags: sql

I was trying to find the MAX price of a column, however I want to also do it in dollar form. How would i use FORMAT in this case.

SELECT MAX(price)
FROM ALBUM;

Answer (score 0):

From this site about [Format for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

All you need is

> SELECT Format (MAX(price),'C') FROM ALBUM

Or if you want to use different currency symbol:

> SELECT Format (MAX(price),'C','en-GB') FROM ALBUM